# Filtering by recommended, shows only 2 pages

Tags: support, bug, filtering, new-nav

Is it normal that when I filter by `recommended`, that I only get 2 pages.

Settings are **filter**: recommended, **show**: all, **sort**: recently active.

Comment: This is by design, it's showing only 100 selected questions (so indeed, 2 pages of 50), as the developer explains in the linked question. (hence dupe)